# How to get Adobe Garamond Pro to work for mathdesign on XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, mathdesign

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
This is a test. 1 $1$.
\end{document}
```

I believe the fonts are installed correctly because this works perfectly with pdflatex and lualatex, but it fails when I use xelatex. On Windows with texlive 2013, I get the following:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9g> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mathdesign.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/mdpgd.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/mdpgd.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdfont.def)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdsffont.def)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdttfont.def)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/ot1mdpgd.fd))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/t1mdpgd.fd))) (./tmp.aux
) (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdacmr.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbcmr.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/omlmdpgd.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/omsmdpgd.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/omxmdpgd.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/mdamdpgd.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdpgd/mdbmdpgd.fd) [1]
(./tmp.aux) )kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `<AGaramondPro-Regular.otf', co
ntains '<'

** WARNING ** Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "mdwgdr8t".
** WARNING ** >> This font is mapped to a physical font "<AGaramondPro-Regular.o
tf".
** WARNING ** >> Please check if kpathsea library can find this font: <AGaramond
Pro-Regular.otf
** ERROR ** Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...

Output file removed.

Error 1 (driver return code) generating output;
file tmp.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on tmp.log.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. `Please check if kpathsea library can find this font: <AGaramond Pro-Regular.otf`. What does `kpathsea` say? Normally for text XeTeX will use system fonts but I think with your set up it is looking for TeX-installed fonts. Have you tried loading `fontspec`?

Comment: @cfr: kpsewhich finds "AGaramondPro-Regular.otf", but it does not find "<AGaramondPro-Regular.otf", of course. I don't know why the "<" appears here.

Comment: In mathdesign the fonts are not used through the normal "fontspec" way but tfm-files are loaded. The actual fonts are found with the help of map-file entries. In texlive xetex (xdvipdfmx) uses pdftex.map. This map use the syntax ` <<AGaramondPro-Regular.otf` (pdftex need it as it can load otf only fully) but obviously  xdvipdfmx gets confused by the two `<<`. You could put corrected map entries in a `mygaramond.map`, save it in fonts/map and then add `f mygaramond.map` to your dvipdfmx.cfg.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer! Some progress has been made, but I'm not quite there. I made `mygaramond.map` with lines like this: `mdwgdr8t AGaramondPro-Regular " AutoEnc_csqf633h5kovjwhnfrdbqmo3bg ReEncodeFont " <[a_csqf63.enc <AGaramondPro-Regular.otf` (changing the << to <), added `f mygaramond.map` to dvipdfmx.cfg, ran mktexlsr and updmap. Now I get a new error after it apparently runs mktexpk and then mktexmf AGaramondPro-Regular.mf. I get mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile! Cannot find AGaramondPro-Regular.mf. I try ps2pk-->gsftopk-->ttf2pk-->hbf2gf. Cannot find AGaramondPro-Regular.tfm.

Comment: I don't have the actual otf so I couldn't run a complete test. Also I copied the map entries for mygaramond.map from the map of miktex. It uses the syntax `mdwgdr7m a_rxz3ga AGaramondPro-Regular`

Comment: I don't think you should add it to `dvipdfmx.cfg` if that is what you did. You can just use `updmap-sys --enable...` to enable the map. The `cfg` file lists the mapping files - not the map file fragments which are used to create them. And use `updmap-sys` for TeX Live unless you absolutely have no choice but to use `updmap`. (And if you've run `updmap`, delete `~/.texlive2013`.) [Unless this is different on Windows?]

Comment: Thanks @cfr! I followed that exactly, and got a different set of errors. I get a set of warnings like `** WARNING ** Found a mismatched fontmap line 13619 from pdftex.map. ** WARNING ** -- Ignore the current input buffer: mdwgdb7m AGaramondPro-Bold a_rxz3ga`. Finally, it says `The command name is C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\mktexmf name = mdwgdr8t, rootname = mdwgdr8t, pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find mdwgdr8t.mf`. I am wondering if there is an issue with mygaramond.map. The lines just are like this: `mdwgdb7m AGaramondPro-Bold a_rxz3ga`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought you had them like this `mdwgdr8t AGaramondPro-Regular " AutoEnc_csqf633h5kovjwhnfrdbqmo3bg ReEncodeFont " <[a_csqf63.enc <AGaramondPro-Regular.otf`?

Comment: @cfr. I tried it that way because of Ulrike Fisher's suggestion. Doing it the way you suggest gets rid of the warning, but I get this error: `The command name is C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\mktexmf
name = AGaramondPro-Regular, rootname = AGaramondPro-Regular, pointsize =
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find AGaramondPro-Regular.mf .
I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf.
Cannot find AGaramondPro-Regular.tfm . kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

** WARNING ** Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "mdwgdr8t".`

Comment: @cfr: It is imho not a good idea to enable such a map generally. It will then also be seen by pdflatex and led to unwanted side effects (even mor if they use the dvipdfmx syntax that pdflatex doesn't understand). The additionaly/change map entries should be seen only by (x)dvipdfmx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good point. You're right, of course.

Comment: After some investigation I would say: It won't work with xelatex. xdvipdfmx can't handle opentype fonts through map files. One must load them with fontspec - which could be difficult if some reencoding is involved.