# Problem using Adobe Garamond Pro with Xelatex on MacPro

Tags: fonts, xetex, opentype, mathdesign, kpathsea

I would like to use the Adobe Garamond Pro (otf) font with `mathdesign` using XeLaTeX. I am running `TexStudio` and `TexLive` on `MacPro`. I have also added these font using `Font Book`:

- AGaramondPro-Regular.otf
- AGaramondPro-Italic.otf
- AGaramondPro-Semibold.otf
- AGaramondPro-SemiboldItalic.otf
- AGaramondPro-Bold.otf
- AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.otf

When I compile this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}% provides font selecting commands

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}



\begin{document}
This is a test. 1 $1$.
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
pathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `<AGaramondPro-Regular.otf', contains '<' xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...

Output file removed.

Process exited normally
```

I have tried many things. But I could not get ride of it. Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE!

Comment: @paul-gessler I would be greatly appreciated in case you might be of any help. Any advice or idea?

Comment: @DG' It does have an `adobe-garamond` option. Look in the `.sty` file. Amir: See [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183000/how-to-get-adobe-garamond-pro-to-work-for-mathdesign-on-xelatex?rq=1#comment422488_183000) on a previous discussion - I'm not sure that `mathdesign` can do this. It seems to be intended for use with type1 versions of the fonts.

Comment: @cfr Ah, I see...